# How to migrate both data and logs in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to change the default `data` and `logs` directory as part of a fresh MongoDB install. First and foremost, this is how I install MongoDB:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

$ echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
$ echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

$ sudo service mongod start

$ tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Then, I try MongoDB a little bit:

```
$ mongo

> use mydb;

> use mydb2;

> db;

> db.employeedetails.insert({"first" : "XYZ1" , "last" : "XYZ2"});

> db.employeedetails.find();
```

Finally I try to change the two corresponding paths, but MongoDB fails badly :(

```
$ sudo service mongod stop

$ mkdir -p $XZY_PATH/mongodb

$ sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf

# update this:
dbPath: $XZY_PATH/mongodb

# as well as this:
path: $XZY_PATH/mongod.log

$ sudo service mongod start
```

**EDIT**

The `$ sudo service mongod start` returns: `mongod start/running, process 10777`, but wen I do `$ mongo`, I get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: test
2015-11-24T15:38:28.775+0200 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-11-24T15:38:28.778+0200 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

Is there something I have missed?

Comment: > Is there something I have missed?

Yes, you forgot to tell what the problem is

Comment: updated my question. thanks!

Comment: Is anything written to the log file? And why are you moving it?